# Help with the naive definition in probability using in the continuous variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

I'm starting to study statistics more seriously and I'm trying to get rid with my old wrong views, mostly regarding the use of the naive definition of probability.

A professor told me if we have to pick randomly by chance one number between 1 to 1000 (real number interval), the chance to take a specific number, let's say 10, it's zero, because by naive definition we would end up with infinity in the denominator (since we are dealing with a continuous interval).

I'm studying a definition which uses the area of a function to defined the probability, so in this case, the probability would be zero, because a single number, in this case a single line, have area 0.

My question is, what it would be a formal answer to this question? the question doesn't make sense since we are dealing with continuous variables or it's zero?

Comment: "pick randomly by chance one number between 1 to 1000": an integer or a real number?

Comment: @Henry a real number

Answer (score 4):

If you are choosing a real number uniformly from the interval $[1,1000]$ then

- the *probability density* is $\frac{1}{999}$ for any particular number on that interval;
- the *probability* of choosing a number in the interval $[a,b]$ with $1 \le a \le b\le 1000$ is then $\frac{b-a}{999}$ as you can find by integration
- the *probability* of any particular number $a$ in that interval (i.e. $b=a$) is then $0$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, how did you find the probability density?

Comment: @user42912: It is uniform (i.e. a constant $k$) over the interval $[1,1000]$ so you want the probability $(b-a)k$ to be $1$ when $a=1$ and $b=1000$ making $k=\frac{1}{1000-1}$

Comment: So I'm really confused, please see this: https://imgur.com/a/8YjaAKy it's from Hogg's statistical inference book

Comment: he says we can't assign probabilities to individual points, so for him it's not zero, it's simply undefined.

Comment: @user42912 For a continuous random variable $X$ you have $P(X < x)=P(X\le X)$ and so $P(X=x)=0$ for all $x$: this is either the definition of a *continuous* distribution or an immediate consequence.  This is not particularly useful as adding probabilities of disjoint events only works for countable sums and you need uncountable sums in this case.